# php user-defined-function parameter scope assignment issue

Tags: php, scope, user-defined-functions

after php code row 1 and 2, I got a notice and error message.

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbc in ...
>   Warning: mysqli_get_host_info()
>   expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ...

```
connectdb();
echo mysqli_get_host_info($dbc);
```

Can you help me please to solve my notice & warning? 
How can I make $dbc defined also for outher functions? I am  working with error level -1 by the time being. please don't tell not to display the notices as a solution. Unfortunately, I can't understand the custom function variable passage issues. thanks.

```
function connectdb() 
{
    $dbc = mysqli_connect (db_host, db_user, db_password, db_name);
    if (!$dbc) 
        {
            $txt = mysqli_connect_errno().mysqli_connect_error();
            db_connect_error_mail($txt);
            unset ($txt);
            die('error message.');
        } 
    else 
        {
            return $dbc;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are db_host, db_user etc constants? If not you are missing some dollar signs.

Comment: thanks Jrod, yes they are constants.

Comment: thanks Michael, I already posted. please look at numbered two rows at the beginning of my post. connectdb() and then ...

Comment: functions are included from a functions.php page into index.php. after in index.php after some other codes, I called connectdb(); and tried to echo mysqli_get_host_info($dbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning the return value of connectdb() method anywhere.  You want:

```
$connection = connectdb();
echo mysqli_get_host_info($connection);
```

For clarity I have used a different variable name as the one you use in your function, because they are different variables, as they are defined in different scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Think, you are returning `$dbc`, from the function, but you are not assigning the return value of the `connectdb()` function in line 1. How will the compiler know that you saved the return value in `$dbc`?

```
$dbc = connectdb();
```

This will fix your error.